# WCF service attempting to read mdf file

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, wcf, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight application, developed in VS2010 and deployed on Server 2008.

The application calls a WCF service within the project to read an mdf file, again within the application.

After getting through a number of what can only be called bugs within the VS deployement system (missing out the svc.cs file, placing the references in a folder the service can't see)  I have managed to get it running.

The problem I'm having is that the service fails after a few seconds.  Using WCF Storm I was able to run the service and get the following error information:

```
removed, see comments and below
```

has anyone any suggestions as to how to fix this?  I'm getting to the end of my tether with WCF services!

Thanks in advance

Cap

---

Edit:

I have now activated errors in the web.config (thanks Upendra Chaudhari) and it has given the following error:

```
<GetDataTypes>
<MethodParameters>
<FaultException1>
  <Detail>
    <HelpLink isNull="true" />
    <InnerException>
      <HelpLink isNull="true" />
      <InnerException isNull="true" />
      <Message>A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)</Message>
      <StackTrace>at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean&amp; closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)</StackTrace>
      <Type>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException</Type>
    </InnerException>
    <Message>The underlying provider failed on Open.</Message>
    <StackTrace>at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean&amp; closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable&lt;T&gt;.GetEnumerator()   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)   at e_on_silverlight_bing.Web.Services.NewSiteService.GetDataTypes() in C:\Documents and Settings\richardsonl\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\E-on Site Map\SilverlightApplication3\e-on silverlight bing.Web\Services\NewSiteService.svc.cs:line 65   at SyncInvokeGetDataTypes(Object , Object[] , Object[] )   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace>
    <Type>System.Data.EntityException</Type>
  </Detail>
  <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault</Action>
  <Code>System.ServiceModel.FaultCode</Code>
  <Message>The underlying provider failed on Open.</Message>
  <Reason>The underlying provider failed on Open.</Reason>
  <Data>
    <KeysAndValues attr0="KeyValuePairArray" isNull="false" />
  </Data>
  <InnerException isNull="true" />
  <TargetSite>Void HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)</TargetSite>
  <StackTrace>Server stack trace:    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc&amp; rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)Exception rethrown at [0]:    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)   at NewSiteService.GetDataTypes()   at NewSiteServiceClient.GetDataTypes()</StackTrace>
  <HelpLink isNull="true" />
  <Source>mscorlib</Source>
</FaultException1>
```

It looks like the service cannot see the database.  I'm not particularly experienced  with this sort of thing so I may be missing something important.

Within VS2010 I have the mdf file inside App_Data within the webpage.  The service is within the services folder.  I have published the site and moved the files and folders to a new folder within wwwroot.  Any ideas?

Thanks again

Cap

Comment: As per error description, it's not actual error you received. To get actual error, you need to turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults in WCF service then we can have more idea.

Comment: wow, how did I miss that.  It's been a long day.  Thanks :)

Comment: Now error says connection problem to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of these:

> - your connection string is wrong:you must open web.config file in your web part of your project and right that.
> - database system is inaccessible because:
>
>   > - the database computer is turn off
>   > - firewall or antivirus of database system is active